# Get the radio button value every time it changes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to get the value of the radio button every time I change the active radio button in ReactJS, but the code is capturing the first change only.

in JSX

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="yes" onChange={(e) => this.radioChange(e)} />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="no" onChange={(e) => this.radioChange(e)} />
```

and the function

```
radioChange = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

I need to show the selected radio button value in console every time I change the radio button selection

Please help.

Comment: Hi @Neel Debnath please see link http://jsbin.com/vodowiyoda/4/edit?js,output, it has sample of radio button functionality in react.

Comment: Even i post simple  example of react js similar to you're question, Hope it helps you!!!

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Is this a functional or class component?

Comment: @ankitkanojia this is surely helpful, Thanks for you time :)

Comment: @ggorlen this is a class component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  radioChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="yes" onChange={(e) => this.radioChange(e)} /> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="no" onChange={(e) => this.radioChange(e)} /> No
      </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still in my browser console, only the first response is showing.

Comment: Working now, I had checked on off the value in default. After removing this, it is working. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So I guess the problem was that OP used an arrow function when they should have used a class function? A bit of description of *why* this solves the problem is always welcome for future visitors' benefit.